# CTI sendCTIMessage function from lighting component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, cti

How to make call to CTI sendCTIMessage function from lighting component. I have LWC component from where I want to make call to CTI. Is It possible to call `sforce.console.cti.sendCTIMessage(message, integrationCallback);` from LWC or aura components.

Answer (score 2):

The open CTI is not yet supported for lwc. You can embed the lwc component into aura components but you will need to use events or lightning messaging service (LMS) to communicate back and forth.

Here is a reference from Salesforce docs on how to work with the CTI using lightning messaging service https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_sample_lex_message_service.htm)

The better approach would be to build a aura component and then use all the open CTI methods available to you without having to worry about writing additional logic to make aura and lwc work.

Comment: I was trying to find sendCTIMessage CTI API in Lighting. But dint found any. Do you have any idea in Lighting CTI similar api to sendCTIMessage classic.

Comment: Yes check my updated answer

Comment: You will be using LMS to subscribe and publish everything to a channel. In aura and lwc you can define a listener as well for this.